# Vuejs 2 Image Src Attributes

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

Vuejs likers  help!

I have this image loop with image source. Here is the code.

```
<img :src="'../../'+ photo.path" alt="product" height="207" width="175" v-for="photo in product.photos" v-if="photo.is_primary === 1" />
```

I should replace this prefix to base url to be reusable.

```
../../
```

How? TY

Answer (score 3):

When you do :src="value", it gets the value from computed/data so just build the url in computed properties

```
yourUrl (){
    //build your url here, can be base url or whatever
    return url
}

//html
:src="yourUrl"
```

That should be it.

Comment: I add it in `data{ base_url: window.location.origin }` is it good or bad?

Comment: @Rbex thats fine

Answer (score 2):

You can tell Webpack to handle this as a dependency by using `require()`:

```
<img :src="require('../../' + photo.path)" alt="..." />
```

This will make the path relative to the build files instead of relative to the component file.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I looked high and low before finally finding this solution. Thanks!

Comment: Also, the '@' alias for 'src' comes in handy here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to add a base URL that you'll use in multiple components and you don't want to have to change it in each?

You can create a config.js or whatever you want to name it, in your src folder or wherever and add

```
export const baseUrl = 'my/img/base'
```

Then in whichever component you want to append that baseUrl,

```
import { baseUrl } from '@/src/config'

data () {
  return {
    baseUrl: baseUrl 
    ...
  }
}
```

Change the path to the location of your config.